# What is the next Pattern in the image

Tags: logic

I want to know how to find the next pattern

[image]

Comment: This looks more like a question for [Puzzling SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In question 5.

In first diagram I am treating place with digit 5 as 1st quadrant.

Place with 9 as 2nd quadrant.

Place with H as 3rd quadrant.

And place with E as 4th quadrant.

There is 2 numbers and 2 letters in each diagram.

Each element in circle rotated anti-clockwise. And element in 2nd quadrant eliminated. And new element placed in 4 quadrant.

Using this logic we have 7 in 1st quadrant, 3 in 2nd quadrant, L in 3rd quadrant. And one new element placed in 4th quadrant. Only D satisfies all conditions. So answer is D.

Any doubt please ask.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I would like to know if there is any logic for putting O in the fourth quandrant

Comment: No logic. We need to depend on options also to answer these type of questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have answered my doubt which was nagging me for many days

Comment: Mine pleasure. When I started learning reasoning. I have same problems many time.